# UML Sequence Diagram WindowListener

Tags: java, uml, sequence-diagram

I'm just starting to learn how to write Sequence Diagrams for Java programs at the moment.

I have the task to write a Sequence Diagram for a given Java Class called KeyTest that extends the java.awt.Frame class. In this diagram, a KeyListener and a WindowListener is added to the KeyTest class via `this.addKeyListener(this)`. How do I implement that and the KeyPressed, KeyTyped and KeyReleased Operations in the Sequence Diagram?

For some reason we have only been told how to add an ActionListener to a button, but not to the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

All those are operations of a class. And these correspond to messages sent from somewhere to this class, triggering the execution of the operation. Just like so:

[image]

The fact that `KeyTest` extends `java.awt.Frame` goes to a class diagram and will be shown with a generalization.